# awk search pattern in a specific field and replace its content

Tags: awk

I need to found field of password that is empty, with space or tab, and replace it with x (on /etc/passwd file)

I found this syntax with awk, that show users where second field (using : as delimiter) is or empty, or has space or tab inside:

```
awk -F":" '($2 == "" || $2 == " " || $2 == "\t") {print $0}' $file
```

and result is the follow:

```
user1::53556:100::/home/user1:/bin/bash
user2: :53557:100::/home/user2:/bin/bash
user3:  :53558:100::/home/user3:/bin/bash
```

How I can say to awk to replace this 2nd field (empty or with space or tab)  with another character? (for example  x)

Comment: You just need `awk '$2 == "" || $2 == " " || $2 == "\t" { $2 = "x" }1' FS=: OFS=: /etc/passwd `

Comment: Great, output result is ok  but content inside file does not change.

Can awk write result directly inside $file (avoiding last line resuls with :x)?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {$2=$2=="" || $2~/^[[:space:]]+$/?"X":$2} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation of above code.

```
awk '                                          ##Starting awk program here.
BEGIN{                                         ##Starting BEGIN section here which will be executed before Input_file is being read.
  FS=OFS=":"                                   ##Setting FS and OFS as colon here for all lines of Input_file.
}                                              ##Closing BEGIN section block here.
{
  $2=$2=="" || $2~/^[[:space:]]+$/?"X":$2      ##Checking condition if $2(2nd field) of current line is either NULL or having complete space in it then put its vaklue as X or keep $2 value as same as it is.
}
1                                              ##mentioning 1 will print edited/non-edited current line.
' Input_file                                   ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** As per OP, OP need NOT to touch last line of Input_file so adding following solutio now.

```
tac Input_file | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} FNR==1{print;next} {$2=$2=="" || $2~/^[[:space:]]+$/?"X":$2} 1' | tac
```

---

---

***EDIT2:*** In case you want to do it kin single `awk` itself then try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=":"
}
prev{
  num=split(prev,array,":")
  array[2]=array[2]=="" || array[2]~/^[[:space:]]+$/?"X":array[2]
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    val=(val?val OFS array[i]:array[i])
  }
  print val
  val=""
}
{
  prev=$0
}
END{
  if(prev){
    print prev
  }
}'  Input_file
```

In case you want to change Input_file itself append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` in above code.

Comment: This is computationally lower performing than the logic I have. Because this gets executed for all the lines inside because you have defined the action inside the `{..}` as an `if`. Moving it out will be better for lines that don't match as the part `{..}` won't even be attempted

Comment: Great, this works too but content inside file does not change. Can awk write result directly inside $file (avoiding last line resuls with :x)?

Comment: @MrJohn, Added details now, how you could save changes into Input_file itself. IMHO first simply run iyt and see output on terminal and then perform that append command which I have added in my post to save changes into Input_file for safer side. let me know if any queries on same.

Comment: @MrJohn, also not sure why you are having `$file` in you attempt, `$file` means a variable named file and you are passing its value as Input_file name to `awk` command, so be aware of that too.

Comment: @MrJohn, can you please be clear here you want to leave last line either its 2nd field is empty or not?

Comment: file="/etc/password"

Comment: > temp_file && mv temp_file $file it works fine! thanks a lot @RavinderSingh13

Comment: last little problem is that results add at last line :x. I solved piping : | sed 's/^:x//' to remove it.

Comment: so, complete command which does what I asked is : 

awk -F: '$2 == "" || $2 == " " || $2 == "\t" { $2 = "x" }1' OFS=: $file | sed 's/^:x//' > temp_file && mv temp_file $file

Comment: @MrJohn, please check my EDIT command now, it will LEAVE last line without checking. Once you are OK with EDIT command then append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` to my EDIT command to save changes into Input_file itself, let me know?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  yes it works :-)  Thanks a lot for you support!!

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  I'm trying to rate your answer UP but without success. I get this message "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: @MrJohn, np(even I forgot that :) ). Give it sometime and when you see some answers to your question you could select anyone of them as correct one(and this you could do for all your questions to thank anyone on SO for right answers), cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} (NF>1) && ($2~/^[[:space:]]*$/){$2="x"} 1' file
user1:x:53556:100::/home/user1:/bin/bash
user2:x:53557:100::/home/user2:/bin/bash
user3:x:53558:100::/home/user3:/bin/bash
```

To change the original file using GNU awk:

```
awk -i inplace 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} (NF>1) && ($2~/^[[:space:]]*$/){$2="x"} 1' file
```

or with any awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} (NF>1) && ($2~/^[[:space:]]*$/){$2="x"} 1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

The test for `NF>1` ensures we only operate on lines that already have at least 2 fields and so we don't create a line like `:x` in the output when there's an empty line in the input file. The rest is hopefully obvious.